# System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: android

I'm getting this exception System services not available to Activities before `onCreate()` when I'm trying to set adapter outside of my `onCreate()` method.

I have tried using `runOnUIThread()` function but still couldn't solve my problem.
Here is my code actually.
 I'm sending a list from my Service subclass to my activity class via a method.

```
Class KitchenSerivce extends Service
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags , int startId)
{   
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);   
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try
    {
        SoapObject result=null;
        SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAME_SPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        try
        {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransportSE=new HttpTransportSE(URL, 5000);
            androidHttpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
            orderList=getOrder(result);

            Log.v("Server response", result.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            msg=Toast.makeText(this, "Connection to Server Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            msg.show();             
        }

        msg=Toast.makeText(this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        msg.show();

        KitchenManager kitchen=new KitchenManager();        
        kitchen.sendOrder(orderList);
    }                   
    catch (Exception e)     
    {               
        System.out.println("Exception Caught:"+e.getMessage());         
    }

    return START_STICKY;        
}
```

---

**KitchenManager extends Activity**

```
public void sendOrder(List<Order> orderList)
{

    this.orderList=orderList;

    for(int i=0;i<orderList.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println("List Size:"+orderList.size());
        System.out.println("Item:"+orderList.get(i).getItem());
    }

    adapter=new OrdersAdapter(KitchenManager.this,R.layout.kitchen_order_list,this.orderList);

    if(this.orderList.size()==0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

---

I'm getting exception in public void `sendOrder()` on line

```
adapter=new OrdersAdapter(KitchenManager.this,R.layout.kitchen_order_list,this.orderList);
```

Please if any one could help me because I'm done searching but can't find solution to my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
KitchenManager kitchen=new KitchenManager();
```

**Don't try to do this!!!**

You cannot instantiate an `Activity` using `new`. This is NOT how Android works.

If you want to start an `Activity` from a `Service` you should do it using a `Notification` and a `PendingIntent`.

Comment: @VipulShah : It took me a while to spot it. :)

Comment: @Squonk ok if i use pending intent how come i send my array list??

Comment: @RajaBabar : Make `Order` implement `Serializable` and use `ArrayList<Order>` instead. `Bundle` has a method where you can put a `Serializable` object. Alternatively make `Order` a `Parcelable` object and you can still use `List<Order>`. It's more efficient for Android but a little more difficult to do than `Serializable`.

Comment: @Squonk so after that would i have to start the activity if so then how to handle bundle thing over there...because i actually remain in the same activity??

Comment: @Squonk can you please write some lines of code so i can get an idea what to do??

Comment: @Squonk actually i dont want to start the activity i simply want to get the list which i actually receive in my non Activity class i.e KitchenService extends Service...so please tell me a solution to this

Comment: @RajaBabar : I don't fully understand. You want to display the list of the order in an Activity which is already open...correct? If so then have the KitchenManager Activity use a nested BroadcastReceiver and send the list as an Intent extra to it.

Comment: @Squonk yes i want to use the List<Order> orderList to set to my adapter in my activity which is already opened...no i didnt use BroadcastReceiver...

Comment: @RajaBabar : OK, so create an inner/nested `BroadcastReceiver` class in the `KitchenManager` class and have it listen to `com.mycompany.myapp.PROCESS_ORDER` (for example). Register the receiver in the `Activity` `onResume` method and unregister in `onPause`. Then make the `Service` create a broadcast `Intent` with the `com.mycompany.myapp.PROCESS_ORDER` action and provide the order as an `extra` for the `Intent`.

Comment: @Squonk http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html in this article no 8 points to the same thing but i dont understand AlarmManager will automaticall start the service but in the onReceive() of Broadcast Receiver service is explicitly started??

Answer (score 0):

You should consider redesigning your code.

I will point you where are you wrong.

You have problem in following code.

```
 public void sendOrder(List<Order> orderList)
```

You are calling this method from KitchenSerivce and expecting it to work with context of KitchenManager

Rather you should change your method to following.

```
public void sendOrder(Context context,List<Order> orderList)
```

Inside you KitchenService include following.

```
class KitchenService extends Service {
        private Context context;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            context = KitchenService.this;
            super.onCreate();
        }
```

and while calling  `kitchen.sendOrder(orderList);` change it to

```
 kitchen.sendOrder(context,orderList);
```

and then change this

```
adapter=new OrdersAdapter(KitchenManager.this,R.layout.kitchen_order_list,this.orderList);
```

to

```
adapter=new OrdersAdapter(context,R.layout.kitchen_order_list,this.orderList);
```

Comment: what to do with the context inside the sendOrder()??

Comment: @VipulShah : See my answer. The OP is trying to create an instance of an `Activity` using `new`. It is never going to work.

Comment: @RajaBabar You should seriously think about redesigning your code.

Comment: @VipulShah im bit confused can u explain a bit...how come adapter gonna work with the context of other class.whilst it is in my activity class and also gonna be setted with the ListView of the activity class??

Comment: @VipulShah can you please tell me now what should i do to solve it??